# Sharing Application Data in Google Drive for installed desktop app & android app

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I was intent to use https://developers.google.com/drive/web/appdata, so that my Android app & Java desktop app able to exchange data among themselves.

Currently, the Android project had enabled Google Drive API OAuth 2.0 credential under "myapp-android" project name.

I was wondering, in order for the uploaded data visible among my Android app & Java desktop app, must my Java desktop app also create OAuth 2.0 credential for installed app, under "myapp-android" project?

The reason I ask so, as I feel uncomfortable, for a single project shared by both Android and Java desktop.